# how am i supposed to use multiple buffers in OpenGL

Tags: c#, opengl, 3d, rendering, opentk

i want to use different arrays to store different data like the color postion and texture coords from my mesh but when i try and bind multiple buffers nothing is showing on screen.

if you have any idea on thow to fix please let me know

this is my render class:

```cs
    class Renderer
    {
        public int VertextArrayObject;

        public int VertexBufferObject;

        public int IndexBuffer;

        public int TextureCoordBuffer;

        public Renderer()
        {
            VertextArrayObject = GL.GenVertexArray();

            VertexBufferObject = GL.GenBuffer();

            TextureCoordBuffer = GL.GenBuffer();

            IndexBuffer = GL.GenBuffer();

            GL.ClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);

        }

        public void Draw(Shader shader, Matrix4 transform, Mesh mesh, Game game)
        {
            shader.Use();

            GL.BindVertexArray(VertextArrayObject);

            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, IndexBuffer);
            GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, new IntPtr(sizeof(uint) * mesh.vertexIndices.Length), mesh.vertexIndices, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);

            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, VertexBufferObject);
            GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, new IntPtr(sizeof(float) * (mesh.vertices.Length * 3)), mesh.vertices, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);

            GL.BindVertexArray(0);
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, 0);
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, 0);

            shader.SetMatrix4("model", transform);
            shader.SetMatrix4("view", game.view);
            shader.SetMatrix4("projection", game.projection);

            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, VertexBufferObject);
            int vertexLocation = shader.GetAttribute("aPosition");
            GL.VertexAttribPointer(vertexLocation, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 0, 0);

            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, TextureCoordBuffer);
            int texCoordLocation = shader.GetAttribute("aTexCoord");
            GL.VertexAttribPointer(texCoordLocation, 2, VertexAttribPointerType.UnsignedInt, false, 0, 0);

            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, IndexBuffer);

            GL.DrawElements(PrimitiveType.Triangles, mesh.vertexIndices.Length, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, 0);
        }

    }
```

if there is a better way of doing this other then the multi buffer thing i would love to hear it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with C# or OpenTK, but could it be that the calls to `glEnableVertexAttribArray` and `glVertexAttribPointer` (for the VBOs) are missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable the vertex attributes:

```
GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, VertexBufferObject);
int vertexLocation = shader.GetAttribute("aPosition");
GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(vertexLocation);
GL.VertexAttribPointer(vertexLocation 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 0, 0);

GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, TextureCoordBuffer);
texCoordLocation = shader.GetAttribute("aTexCoord");
GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(texCoordLocation);
GL.VertexAttribPointer(texCoordLocation, 2, VertexAttribPointerType.UnsignedInt, false, 0, 0);
```

See also [Vertex Array Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object)